# regular expression for matching everything until a word is found

Tags: python, regex, textmatching

I have a piece of text that is repeated several times. Here you have a sample of that text:

[DEMO of the text](https://regex101.com/r/52andj/1/)

The idea is to have a regular expression with three groups and repeat this for any match along with the text. Here you have an example of a possible match:

> ```
> group1 = HORIZON-CL5-2021-D1-01
> group2 (Opening) = 15 Apr 2021
> group3 (Deadlines(s)) = 07 Sep 2021
>
>
> group1 = HORIZON-CL5-2022-D1-01-two-stage
> group2 (Opening) = 04 Nov 2021
> group3 (Deadlines(s)) = 15 Feb 2022 (First Stage), 07 Sep 2022 (Second Stage)
> ```

I am trying with this regular expression:

```
\n(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]{1}\d{1}-\d{2}).*?^Opening
```

It almost works. What I need is to say in the regular expression two more things:

1. That there are cases that after the last number of HORIZON... might appear some text, like in the second case:

> HORIZON-CL5-2022-D1-01 **-two-stage**

2. I need to say catch everything until the word 'Opening:' appears at the beginning of a line. I thought was doing this with this part of the expression  `.*?^Opening` but it seems is not correct.

How can I solve this?

Comment: There is no line starting with `Opening` in your text. `(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}).*?Opening` matches your texts. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITx83I/1).

Comment: Ok, there may appear `-two-stage` after a number, what should happen then?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it was my fault. When I copied the text on the question it didn't have the same structure. I edited the question and put a DEMO in regex101 to make it clear. Here you have the link: https://regex101.com/r/52andj/1/

Comment: Perhaps like this `\n(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}[^\r\n]*).*?(?=^Opening)` https://regex101.com/r/hX0GtT/1

Comment: Then your regex just matches the `Opening`. If you want to "exclude" it from the match, put it into a lookahead. Or, if you want to keep on matching till end of string if it is not found use `\n(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]{1}\d{1}-\d{2}).*?(?=^Opening|\z)`

Comment: Or without the s modifier `^(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}.*)(?:\r?\n(?!Opening\b).*)*` https://regex101.com/r/Mu36N4/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it is almost what I need, but I need to include 'Opening:' in the full match and add a group with the date and continue the selection until the 'Deadline(s):' and add a third group with the date

Comment: @nekovolta Ok, np.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `-two-stage` in group 1, you can add matching 0+ non whitespace chars `\S*` to the existing group.

You don't need the `s` modifier to make the dot match a newline. Instead, you can match all lines that do not start with *Opening* using a negative lookahead, and then match *Opening* and capture the date and the deadline part in a capture group.

Note that you can omit `{1}`

```
^(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}\S*)(?:\r?\n(?!Opening\b).*)*\r?\nOpening: (.+)\r?\nDeadline\(s\): (.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P59dro/1)

You could make the group starting with a date like part as specific as you want, as `.+` is a broad match.

For example

```
^(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}\S*)(?:\r?\n(?!Opening\b).*)*\r?\nOpening: (\d{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{4})\r?\nDeadline\(s\): (\d{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{4}.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhTqhX/1)

Comment: When I asked the question, I tried to simplify the question to make it easy to understand. Obviously, your solution works, but when I try to use it in the real example it doesn't work. Why? Here you have a DEMO of my real case with your solution: https://regex101.com/r/94CIYE/1

Comment: @nekovolta That is a lot of text, and the regex101 tool gives you Catastrophic Backtracking. This might be a bit more optimized version `^(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}\S*)(?:\r?\n.*)*?\r?\nOpening: (.+)\r?\nDeadline\(s\): (.+)` but for that text you will get the same message. Did you try reading the file and then get the results like `file = open("test.txt")
text = file.read()
pattern = r"^(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]\d-\d{2}\S*)(?:\r?\n.*)*?\r?\nOpening: (.+)\r?\nDeadline\(s\): (.+)"
print(re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE))`

Comment: I didn't try because since I discovered regex101 I use it to verify that it works as I expect. What does it mean a 'Catastrophic Backtracking'?

Comment: You can read about it on for example [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) or [this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. In your pattern you are reppeated HORIZON-... in the first group e.g. `HORIZON-()-A1-11HORIZON-+-B2-33` while this should not appear in your input it should not be a problem.
2. The Opening is required in your pattern, I would replace it with a positive lookahead `(Opening|$)`, where `$` denotes end of line.
3. It seems you are not doing anything with the parts of the string you are retrieving, from your examples I think you could simply match non-spaces.

```js
const pattern = /\n(HORIZON-\S+)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=Opening|$)/
```

4. If yow want to keep the original pattern and capture the rest of the text in a separate group it would be `/\n(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]{1}\d{1}-\d{2})(\S*)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=Opening|$)/`. The
5. The expression beginning in '\n' does not match the first line, you could change it to `/^(HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]{1}\d{1}-\d{2})(\S*)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=Opening|$)/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this: `HORIZON-\S+-[A-Z]{1}\d{1}-\d{2}(-[^\s]*)?` . I added the `(-[^\s]*)?` part. Here I am telling the regex to match something that starts with `-` until a white space (`\s`) is found. The `?` makes this part optional so it can show up once or not at all.

Comment: it is not exactly that what I need. In fact, I need to catch all the titles that start with HORIZON, in both cases, when it has 'two stages' and when it doesn't. Please check the DEMO link here: regex101.com/r/hX0GtT/1